# Bean Validation on complex objects - Kotlin Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, annotations, bean-validation, data-class

I have a data class that is being validated except for the contents of the lists

```
data class EmailDto(
    @get:Valid
    @get:NotEmpty
    val recipients: List<@Email String>,
    @get:NotBlank
    val subject: String,
    @get:Valid
    val cc: List<@Email String> = listOf(),
    @get:Valid
    val bcc: List<@Email String> = listOf(),
)
```

So my problem is if I use a value of `listOf()` for `recipients` the validation fires and gives me an exception, whereas `listOf("test.com")` does not cause an exception when it should since the string value isn't a valid email address.

I've tried all different kinds of targets on the annotations and omitted them but I can't seem to get any validation to work on complex fields. Does anyone have any insight on this? I haven't been able to really track anything down searching online.

Comment: Did you try it without @Email keyword?

Comment: @nicowi Yeah, I’ve tried “@NotBlank” in place of “@Email”. That didn’t work either.